# FilePathField for Image Path not working with Django Admin Panel

Tags: python, django, static, django-admin

New to Django and web development in general. But I have followed a [tutorial](https://realpython.com/get-started-with-django-1/) for creating my first site. Everything worked fine, until I finished it and wanted to edit the info using the Django admin panel.

The main issue is that I have a model shown below that uses FilePathField to describe the image locations. The tutorial had me place the images in `/home/pi/mysite/projects/static/img`.

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    technology = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.FilePathField('/img')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title #or self.title for blog posts
```

This worked fine at first for displaying the images on the website, but once I tried to navigate to the `/change/` url from the admin panel, I would get `FileNotFoundError at /admin/projects/project/1/change/ [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/img'`

So I looked around and found that FilePathField is an absolute path, so tried defining it absolutely with `/home/pi/mysite/projects/static/img/`. This stopped the error from occurring which let me at least access the `/change/` url from the admin panel. The panel now showed the image field with a dropdown that I could use to choose between the different images I had up there, which were located at `/home/pi/mysite/projects/static/img/`. But from the admin panel, once I hit save, the images would no longer show up on the site. Upon using inspect element on the website, it seems it was trying to pull the images from `/static/projects/static/img`. I then tried to move the images to `/static/projects/static/img` but then they no longer showed up in the dropdown box from the admin panel, and also weren't displaying on the website.

So at this point I am just a bit confused where I should be pointing FilePathField too that will allow me to display the images on the website and also change them through the admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much better approach is to use django's `FileField` like so:

```py
image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

In your `settings.py` you need to include the media path. Check you have this in your settings.

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media').replace('\\', '/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Last step is to extend the urlpatterns in your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # your paths
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This will generate a `/media/` directory where your uploaded media files will point to. Then in your frontend you can simply use the model property `image.url` to get the absolute url of the image.

Comment: Thanks! That does seem a lot easier on the admin panel. The pictures I can directly access from the browser now by going to `/media/project1.png` however they still aren't showing on the website on the proper page. When inspecting the images they're still trying to load from `/static/project1.png`. For the page template I have this to show the images `<img class="card-img-top" src="{% static project.image %}">`. Still not entirely sure how everything works but tried to change static to media within there but no change. So from that <img class> is there something else I should be putting there?

Comment: Figured it out, changed it to `src={{ project.image.url }}` and that fixed it.